# Why does this fail in pyscripter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyscripter

This question started as a simple Python 3.x question but now I'm not sure what is going on.  When I run the following code in a shell it works fine.  When I run it in PyScripter the result is always 0 0.  Has anyone seen this problem before?  My search of the FAQ and bug reports don't come up with anything.

```
# Simple CheckButton example
# CH 3/24/13

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

#function to display checkbutton values
def showVal():
    print(cb1Val.get(), cb2Val.get())

# define value variables
# cb1Val and cb2Val hold 1 if checked and 0 if not
cb1Val = tk.IntVar()
cb2Val = tk.IntVar()

# make instances of my widgets
cb1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='cb1', variable=cb1Val)
cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='cb2', variable=cb2Val)

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=showVal)

# place widgets into the frame
cb1.grid(row=0,column=0)
cb2.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn1.grid(row=2, column=0)

#start the loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just changed the engine from "remote (Tk)" to "remote" and it now works fine.  Go figure.

Comment: I finally found my own solution. Here is a website that explains the difference. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/pyscripter/W4xHJ5gvsxM/vGhwbdyvbIEJ. Changing the `root = tk.Tk()` to `root = tk.Toplevel()` solves the problem.